# how to text-align: center with this flex schema?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is this scenario doable with flex? Cause I can't `text-align:center` item2 (full width).

```
<div class="container">
<div class="item1"></div>
<div class="item2"></div>
</div>
```

[image: flex problem]

EDIT:
I did change the image cause container color was white (as page background)...

Comment: Provide a complete example

Answer (score 0):

You can make both item1 and item2 as display:flex and make justify-content:center and align-items:center that would center the content on those divs

check the snippet

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
.container div {
  background: black;
  color: red;
}
.item1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.item2 {
  margin-left: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1">text</div>
  <div class="item2">text</div>
</div>
```

hope it helps

Comment: make both item1 and item2 as display:flex and make item2 width:100%; did the trick. Thank you! I wasn't aware that I can make both items display:flex;... I thought there must be container that has this property.

Comment: BTW: if item1 is an image and you don't want to put width and height vertical-align:middle; will do the trick to position it vertically at center, align-items (align-self) and justify-content:center; weren't working for me.

Comment: as you have asked for the flex i have provided flex solution...did solution helped you any way or if you want anything more i can modify the solution accordingly

Comment: No thanks @Geeky your solution is working fine! Thanks.

Comment: I did vote it up but my point for you will be show if I get 15 rep.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using `flex: grow;` for **.item1** and **.item2**

**CSS:**

```
.container {
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
   width: 700px;
   background-color: black;
   padding:33px;
   vertical-align:middle;
}

.item1 {
   flex-grow: 1;
   background: yellowgreen;
   height:200px;
   margin: 15px;
   text-align: center;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center
}

.item2 {
   flex-grow: 2;
   background: aquamarine;
   height:200px;
   margin: 15px;
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: center;
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item1">text</div>
    <div class="item2">text</div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e3uskneh/)